# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null

Tags: html, javascript

Здравствуйте!

Я пытаюсь добавить элемент div в DOM, а в ответ получаю ошибку:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null

HTML-код:

```
<html> 
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="source.js"></script> 
    <div id="something">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript-код (файл source.js):

```
var div = document.createElement("div");

div.innerHTML = "Something new..."; 
document.getElementById("something").appendChild(div);
```

С чем это связано?

Comment: оберните код в `onload`, т.к. на момент выполнения кода `<div id="something">` ещё не был создан и поэтому `.getElementById("something")` возвращает `null`

Answer (score 2):

[@Spectre](/users/3159/spectre) дал правильное объяснение: на момент выполнения кода элемент `<div id="something" />` еще не создан. Поэтому нужно перенести выполнение кода на момент, когда div уже будет создан. Например:

```
<body>
    <div id="something">
    </div>
    <script src="source.js"></script> 
</body>
```